# Put Request to Firebase with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a PUT request to Firebase with NodeJS.  When I make the following request, the response hangs until it times-out.  No error message makes it difficult to debug--

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var https = require('https');

var data = querystring.stringify({
  'foo': 'bar'
});

var options = {
  host: 'my-app.firebaseio.com',
  port: '80',
  path: '/datetimes.json?auth=password',
  method: 'PUT'

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.write(data);
req.end();
```

My guess is that there is a problem with the Firebase authentication, or else I'd get an error.  But this *does* work--

```
https.get({ host: 'my-app.firebaseio.com', path: '/datetimes.json?auth=password' }, function(res) {
  console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
  console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

  res.on('data', function(d) {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });

}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

So that makes me think maybe the password is okay and I'm just using `https.request` incorrectly?

[I cannot use any NPM libraries (i.e. `request`) because this needs to work with AWS Lambda.]

Comment: Why are you making a put request to firebase? Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve?

To integrate firebase in you Node.js application follow: https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup

Comment: I am trying to execute the PUT request from an AWS Lambda function, so do not have access to the Firebase Node.js SDK.

Comment: @common-nighthawk did you find an answer to this?